# Excel how to deactivate "Most Recently used function" suggestion from drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365, list

I am currently using Office 365 on Mac.

For the "Drop-down Function-suggestion list", Excel have started suggesting the "most recently used" function, as opposed to JUST suggesting it in alphabetical order.

I really want to deactivate these suggestions, as I have "memorized" what to write to get the function I need. With the update I have to stop and look at the list to make sure that it's suggesting the correct function.

As an example (see picture 1), writing "=if" + TAB, should give me the IF-function as suggestion. However, because I recently used IFERROR, it suggest IFERROR instead.

[Function Suggestion Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsyiV.png)

Does anyone know how to deactivate this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Please go to **Excel**->> **Preferences...**->> **AutoComplete**- please uncheck **Use AutoComplete** and **Show AutoComplete options for functions and ranges**:

[image]

[image]

Please try this method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I wasn't clear enough. I want to only remove the "Recently Used suggestions", while keeping the other Auto-complete Suggestion.
For a better example:
If I have used "subtotal()" recently, and then want to use "substitute()". When writing "Sub" and hitting tab, I want "substitute()" to be selected, and not the "subtotal()" (which is most recently used).

Comment: @ErikBoersheim: Did you find a solution? I'd like to completely disable "most recently used" option too. Uncheck the AutoComplete preferences doesn not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple VBA code to deactivate the Auto Completion therefore will also stop the recently used formula to appear in terms of auto complete.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

On Error Resume Next

Do Until Err.Number <> 0
Application.EnableAutoComplete = False
Loop

End Sub
```

You may re-activate the Auto-completion before you close the Workbook. Just use this,,

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

  Application.EnableAutoComplete = True

End Sub
```

*Hope this help you.*